# How can I create a separate plugin folder for my Rails 2.3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have 2 classes of plugins and I like to separate them into

vendor/plugins -> default core plugins
vendor/extensions -> extensions apps that run inside my platform app

The problem is that plugins inside the extensions folder aren't loaded by the platform app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help:

```
config.plugin_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/extensions"
```